# How to prevent kaspersky to destroy my downloaded documents?

Tags: download, libreoffice, kaspersky

Following up on [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037448/variable-downloaded-file-size-in-a-flask-website), I have been contracted to create a tool to generate odt files in a flask website.

When downloaded on particular machines with kaspersky AV, the files are missing bytes, rendering them corrupted and unusable. Disabling kaspersky of course allows the safe download and use of the files. Using another AV such as AVG doesn't cause the problem.

I imagine kaspersky considers them as a threat, but I know them no to be since I am the one creating them from scratch. I haven't installed the AV, and cannot disable it in production. The person is charge of my client's IT service doesn't know how to configure their AV neither to avoid the problem.

Do you have any idea of what can trigger this ? Is there something I can do to bypass the problem ? Or an information I can give to my client's IT service so they can setup their AV not to consider the service as dangerous ?

Since it's an intranet tool, it's not using ssl. Would it help to create a self issued certificated, preventing the AV to snooping in the file, or does it do it on disk write ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, using SSL did the trick. Thank you SO for being a wonderful rubber duck.

Comment: Not sure why the question is downloaded. What does the *rubber duck* reference mean?